# Show/Hide Div on mouse hover table row

Tags: jquery, html-table

I wanted to show a div located on each `table row` when the mouse is over it. So that the `div.tools` of the hovered `table row` will be displayed and hidden on hover out.

Here is my table.

```
<table width="99%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="2" class="main-box">
 <tbody><tr class="dataTableHeadingRow">
 <td class="dataTableHeadingContent">Categories / Products</td>
 <td class="dataTableHeadingContent" align="right">Action&nbsp;</td>
 </tr>

 <tr id="product_37">
   <td class="dataTableContent">
    <a href="#">Cotton Piqué Tennis Shirt</a>
    <div class="tools" style="display:none;">Tools Here</div>
   </td>
   <td class="dataTableContent" align="right">
    <img src="#/images/icon_arrow_right.gif" border="0" alt="">&nbsp;
   </td>
 </tr>

 <tr id="product_39">
   <td class="dataTableContent">
    <a href="#">Leather Plus Cotton Cut-Out Sling Back Sandal</a>
    <div class="tools" style="display:none;">Tools Here</div>
   </td>
   <td class="dataTableContent" align="right">
    <a href="#"><img src="#/images/icon_info.gif" border="0" alt="Info" title=" Info "></a>&nbsp;
   </td>
  </tr>

  <tr id="product_38">
    <td class="dataTableContent">
     <a href="#">Poly-Cotton 3/4 Sleeve Raglan Shirt</a>
    <div class="tools" style="display:none;">Tools Here</div>
    </td>
    <td class="dataTableContent" align="right">
     <a href="#">
     <img src="#/images/icon_info.gif" border="0" alt="Info" title=" Info "></a>&nbsp;
    </td>
  </tr>

  </tbody>
</table>
```

I tried this jQuery function but its not working.

```
jQuery(function() {
 jQuery('*[id^=product_]').hover(function(){
   jQuery(this).children("div.tools").show();
    },function(){
   jQuery(this).children("div.tools").hide();
    });
 });
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `.find()` instead of `.children()`.

The [`.children()` method](http://api.jquery.com/children/) that you're using only finds immediate children, which in the case of your tr elements will be the tds.

The [`.find()` method](http://api.jquery.com/find/) looks amongst all descendants, so it will look inside the tds to find your divs.

You've also got a syntax error that is stopping your code working at all: there's an extra closing `});` at the end that should be removed.

Also, rather than selecting on *all* elements using `*`, it may be more efficient to select just the tr elements within that table:

```
jQuery(function() {
    jQuery('table.main-box tr[id^=product_]').hover(function() {
        jQuery(this).find("div.tools").show();
    }, function() {
        jQuery(this).find("div.tools").hide();
    });
});​
```

Comment: That didn't work because you also have a syntax error: you have an extra closing `});`. Sorry, I didn't notice that at first. Try this: http://jsfiddle.net/nnnnnn/rDThB/1/ (Notice in your fiddle if you press the "Tidy Up" button it fixes the indentation and makes the syntax error more obvious, but also if you check your browser's JS console the error is shown.)